# Advanced Slicing with pandas or numpy for a 2pair and 3 pair, in a 5 group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas table below which can be copy/pasted and read in with pd.read_clipboard(). I need to take a slice of 2 consectutive values, and 3 consecutive values, It's a two pair, three pair list,
as you can see by column y1. So 0,1 is a pair, then 2,3,4 are a pair, and then continues for each 5 group. I need to slice the entire list in these pairs. This is a group of 5, where the first 2 are a pair, and the next three are a pair.
So 14,1 is a pair, and 4,10,8 are a pair, and this is the same for every 5 pair.

```
    what  W1  W2  W8  W9  W0   y   Y   x  y4  y1      
0     14   4  14  12  14   2  15   4   7   1   1      
1      1  11   1   3   1  13   0  14   8  10   1      
2      4  14   4   6   4   8   5   5  13  13   1      
3     10   0  10   8  10   6  11   9   3   8   1      
4      8   2   8  10   8   4   9  12   1   8   1      
5     15  15  13  11  15   0   4  15   4  11  11      
6     11  11   9  15  11   4   0   9   0   2  11      
7      9   9  11  13   9   6   2   0   2  10  11      
8      2   2   0   6   2  13   9   9   9   0  11      
9      0   0   2   4   0  15  11  15  11  10  11      
10     4   6   4  13   4  12  13   6   7   9   9      
11     9  11   9   0   9   1   0   1  10   2   9      
12     3   1   3  10   3  11  10  10   0   7   9      
13     2   0   2  11   2  10  11   3   1  10   9      
14    10   8  10   3  10   2   3  12   9  14   9      
15    13  13   5  14  13   2   6  13   2  11  11      
16    11  11   3   8  11   4   0   4   4   8  11      
17     4   4  12   7   4  11  15   7  11   4  11      
18     8   8   0  11   8   7   3   7   7   4  11      
19     4   4  12   7   4  11  15   9  11   7  11
```

I have tried this which gives the right results, but it doesn't repeat.

```
In [1540]: df['what'][:].to_numpy()[0:2:]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[1540]: array([14,  1], dtype=int8)

In [1538]: df['what'][2:].to_numpy()[0:3:]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1538]: array([ 4, 10,  8], dtype=int8)
```

which is exactly what i want, but it doesn't continue slicing to the end of the list and what i want is it to continue slice so i get all the pairs like belowl:

```
 array([ 4, 10, 8, 9, 2, 0, 3, 2, 10, 4, 8, 4] and the flip side array([14, 1, 15, 11, 4, 9, 13, 11]
```

How do i change my code or use pandas .loc/iloc or numpy slicing to continue slicing like my examples for the entire set?

The reason i need this is because i need to XOR the first two pair by a number, and the second three pair by a separate number. I'd like to XOR the first two pair and set the value in another column, and then XOR the second three pair, and set their values in another column in the correct index location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert data into numpy, then use a boolean of True and False to index the arrays

[numpy resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) helps in matching the boolean to the size of the what array

```
#create array
what = df.what.to_numpy()
what
array([14,  1,  4, 10,  8, 15, 11,  9,  2,  0,  4,  9,  3,  2, 10, 13, 11,
        4,  8,  4], dtype=int64)

#create array of boolean
#ignore first two entries, gimme the next three entries
index = np.array([False,False,True,True,True])

#resize index to match size of what array
index = np.resize(index,what.shape[0])

what[index]
array([ 4, 10,  8,  9,  2,  0,  3,  2, 10,  4,  8,  4], dtype=int64)

#reverse the direction of the boolean
#keep first two entries, ignore next three
what[~index]
array([14,  1, 15, 11,  4,  9, 13, 11], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you, the ability to keep the index size was exactly what i needed. This worked in my program, i tested it. Thanks again